# Quelles règles gouvernent la prononciation du "ch" ?

Tags: étymologie, prononciation, histoire, évolution, grec

Un sondage dans le dictionnaire m'a laissé dans une confusion complète.

"chimie" devrait se prononcer "kimie" d'après l'étymologie *χημεία* ; de plus j'entends en général "kimiothérapie", et le dictionnaire de l'Académie 1784 prescrit de prononcer "alkimie" pour alchimie.

"chien' vient de *canis*, qui se prononçait vraisemblablement "kanis".

Dans un mot plus rare comme "chyle", on peut encore reconnaître *χυλός* (qui maintenant signifie par analogie *porridge*), mais quand l'origine est inconnue, comme "chute", comment deviner ?

Ainsi que pour "chasse", de "*captia*", qui est du bas-latin (le latin classique "*captio*" a un sens très différent, qui a donné "captieux"), comment deviner, ou plutôt déduire ?

Le son "k" est-il devenu "ch" en (très) vieux français, mais réintroduit dans certains mots savants à la Renaissance ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Les règles de prononciation sont excessivement complexes, avec seulement des traits de régularité. Je reporte à ce propos la section relativement complète concernant la prononciation de *ch* qu'on trouve à « [*C*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/c) » dans le TLF.

> C.− *Ch*
>
> 1. À l'initiale
>      a) Se prononce [ʃ] dans les mots français : *chat*, *chercher*, *chimère, chute*.
>      b) Se prononce [k] dans les mots d'origine grecque : *chiromancie*, etc.
> 2. À l'intérieur du mot
>      a) Se prononce [ʃ] quand il est placé entre voyelles. Dans la majorité des mots français : *achalander*, *échec*, *échine*. Dans les mots savants terminés par *-machie* comme : *logomachie*, *tauromachie*. Sauf dans des exceptions du type de *lysimachie* qui se prononce avec [k]; quand il est précédé d'une voyelle et suivi d'une consonne dans les interjections familières : *fichtre!*, *fouchtra!*; quand il est précédé d'une consonne et suivi d'une voyelle dans les groupes suivants : *kch* [kʃ] : *bakchich*; *lch* [lʃ] : *colchicacées*, *colchique*, etc.; *nch* [~ʃ] avec nasalisation de la voyelle précédente : *bronche*, *bronchiole*, *bronchite*, etc. Dans des exceptions du type : *bronchial*, *enchymose*, *inchoatif*, *ch* se prononce [~k] avec nasalisation de la voyelle précédente; *rch* [ʀ ʃ] : *archard*, *archée*, *archevêque*, *archi-*. Dans des exceptions du type : *archaïque*, *archange*, *archétype*, *archiépiscopal*, *orchestre*, *ch* se prononce [k]; quand il est placé entre consonnes dans les groupes suivants : *schk* [ʃk] : *puschkinie*; *schn* [ʃn] : *mischnique*; quand il est précédé de 2 consonnes et suivi d'1 voyelle dans le groupe *ndch* [~ʃ] : *mandchou* (la voyelle précédant *n* étant nasalisée). On peut entendre plus rarement [~tʃ]; quand il est précédé de *schs* : *eschscholzie*.
>      b) *Ch* intérieur se prononce [k] quand il est placé entre voyelles dans des mots savants français : *achaine*, *achéen*, *achillée*, *écho*. Dans certains mots savants *ch* peut aussi se prononcer [ʃ]. P. ex. dans : *machiavélisme*, *monachisme*, *trichine*; il se prononce [k] quand il est précédé d'une voyelle et suivi d'une consonne liquide *l* ou *r* appartenant à la même syllabe (*cochlée*, *isochrome*) ou suivi d'une consonne sourde appartenant à la syllabe suivante (*achtéomètre*, *fuchsine*, *ichthisandre*); dans le groupe *cch* suivi d'une voyelle : *bacchanal*, *bacchante*, *ecchymose*, *saccharine*; quand il est précédé de la consonne *s* et suivi d'une voyelle : *aschariens*, *ascharisme*, *dyschirie*, etc., sauf dans des exceptions du type : *aschée*, *bischofite*, *ischélite*; quand il se trouve placé entre consonnes dans les groupes suivants : *nchn* [~kn] : splanchnique, splanchnologie avec nasalisation de la voyelle précédant le 1er *n*; *nchr* [~kʀ] : *synchrome* avec nasalisation de la voyelle précédant *n*; *schr* [skʀ] : *eschrologie*.
> 3. *Ch* à la finale
>      a) Ne se prononce pas dans *almanach*. b) Se prononce [ʃ] dans des mots turcs ou arabes adoptés par le français : *bakchich*. c) Se prononce [k] dans *cromelech*, *azéradach*, *krach*, *varech*, *auroch*, mots d'origine bretonne, germanique ou scandinave.

La même page comporte également une section historique sur *ch* (HIST. C.). 
Elle indique que la prononciation aspirée du grec est tombée très tôt (*kh* > *k*) dans la prononciation populaire, puis a été dans certains cas sujette à palatalisation (*k* > *ch*). En effet, « à partir de la fin du XV<sup>e</sup> siècle le *h* étymologique tend[ait] à se réintroduire partout ».
Les mots qui ont retrouvé leur *h* à l'écrit n'ont probablement jamais évolué vers le [ʃ].

Comment: Pour compléter : en grec la lettre *χ* (Khi) se prononçait [k].
L'alphabet latin n'avait pas d'équivalent à la lettre *χ* et déjà en latin on utilisait le digramme *ch* pour transcrire le son [k] des mots empruntés au grec.
Ceci à une époque où la lettre h [h] ne se prononçait presque plus. 
L'habitude est restée en ancien français. La lettre h a parfois disparu au fil des siècles, par exemple le grec *χαρακτήρ* a donné le latin *kharaktế* devenu « caractère » en français moderne (alors que l'anglais moderne a conservé le h).

Comment: Cf. [Chi](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi), « En grec ancien, elle était prononcée [kʰ] », et dans les alphabets occidentaux ça a pu donner [ks] et *x*.

Comment: Merci de vos savantes réponses ! Ma conclusion est qu'il faut apprendre la prononciation des mots individuellement, comment se souvenir de règles si complexes en pratique ?

Comment: @MarkThorin, comme dans n'importe quelle langue dont l'orthographe n'est pas phonétique (l'anglais est encore un plus bel exemple que le français d'ailleurs), en apprenant.

Comment: @Un francophone Certes ; mais, essentiellement mathématicien de formation, je cherche plus à comprendre qu'à apprendre, et j'aime des langues comme l'espagnol, l'italien, où l'allemand : j'y perds moins de temps à des futilités. L'anglais m'a été naturellement acquis, mais je ne vais pas le défendre comme cohérence de la correspondance orthographe-phonétique ; néanmoins beaucoup d'aberrations s'expliquent étymologiquement, l'anglais ayant retenu la prononciation française des innombrables mots qu'il a empruntés à cette langue, à l'époque où il les a adoptés.

Comment: @MarkThorin, il me semblait avoir compris qu'un des problème majeur de l'anglais du point de vue de l'orthographe, est qu'elle a été figée au début du _great voyel shift_.  L'orthographe de l'espagnol et du néerlandais sont plus simple parce qu'elles ont été réformées récemment, et il est a peu près certain que si un effort n'est pas fait elles vont s'éloigner de la prononciation progressivement.  Une refonte de l'orthographe du français est désirable; je ne suis pas sûr qu'elle soit sociologiquement possible,...

Comment: @Unfrancophone: On ne peut pas dire que l'orthographe de l'anglais se soit figée au début du GVS. Le GVS a commencé au 12ème siècle. L'orthographe a commencé à se fixer plus tard avec l'introduction (15ème siècle) puis généralisation de l'imprimerie. Pour le GVS voir sujets déjà traités sur                           [EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com) et [linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com). Article sur l'orthographe de l'anglais dans [l'OED](http://public.oed.com/aspects-of-english/english-in-time/early-modern-english-pronunciation-and-spelling/).

Comment: @Unfrancophone: Et on ne peut pas dire que l'orthographe de l'anglais se soit figée, certaines variantes d'anglais continuent à évoluer tant par leurs orthographes que par leurs prononciations, conséquences de la mondialisation. Mais je suis complètement hors sujet...

Comment: Great, so in the absence of a dictionary I have no choice but to guess whether a given word is of Greek or French origin to decide on a pronunciation.

Answer (score 4):

Je voudrais signaler que le mot chimère n'est pas un mot français, c'est un mot grec(χίμαιρα) et pourtant se prononce [ʃ], comme d'ailleirs le mot chirurgien(χειρουργός). Il n' y a donc pas de règle à suivre.