# Why is the "ch" in "technique" pronounced differently than in other words?

Tags: prononciation

Normally the French *ch* is pronounced like the English *sh*, as in French words like *choir*, *chouette*, *choisir*, etc. But in *technique* and its derived words, it's pronounced as a *k*.

Why is that? Is this simply an exception owing to etymological history, or is there a rule about *ch* followed by a consonant?

Comment: Since you saw your question has already been asked you didn't you delete it altogether? I gather you noticed the duplicate after you'd asked the question.

Comment: Well I clicked `delete` and it told me it did not recommend doing so since it deprived future readers etc etc. I figure we have the option to "close as duplicate" for a reason. I only ever delete if I answer the question for myself before anyone posts an answer.

Answer (score 2):

*Chœur*, *chorale*, *chiasme*, *echo*, *dichotomy* are all pronounced [k]. For a consonant after the *ch*, we have: *strychnine*, *chlore*, *chronomètre*, *chthonien*, *chrysanthème*, *Chaldée*, *scholastique*, *chiromancie, orchestre, orchidée, schizophrénie, psychologue, chrétien, chélidoine, chorégraphie* ... looks to me like the Greek origin of all those words led to a [k] sound. Those *ch* were χ in Greek, and that would be the rule, rather than a rule depending on what's before or after the [ch]. A rule with exceptions no doubt.

This [thread](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic30293-prononciation-du-son-ch.html) has more details.

This [french.stackexchange.com](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7930/quelles-r%C3%A8gles-gouvernent-la-prononciation-du-ch) thread also looked at the question.

And the "ultimate" reference is [here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/c).

Comment: I've been wondering about this since that cedilla post: does "ch" perhaps follow the same rules as "c", i.e. hard [k] before certain vowels and consonants and soft [ ʃ ] before other vowels? (Then *cœur* and *chœur* could be consistent.) I have to think of examples to validate either your etymological hypothesis or this one...

Comment: *chaud*, *chapeau* = I'm likely wrong. :p Meanwhile, *chaos* = you're likely right.

Comment: I think it's more related to the etymology. We have the same graphie _ch_ for words that have different etymology. _ch_ was used to render the Greek chi or the latin _c_, and that resulted in different pronunciations. The trick is to confirm where the French _ch_ comes from - the Greek side of the story is IMHO quite clear.

Comment: @LukeSawczak - etymology from Greek or Latin seems to be the primary factor, then there are many secondary rules and/or exceptions.

Comment: This will probably be closed as a duplicate. If that happens, let's beef up the answer that survives with whatever wasn't there, if anything.

Comment: Dichotomy isn't French, dichotomie is.